# How does ordering of reactive statements in Svelte work?

Tags: svelte

In the [Svelte documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) it says:

> It is important to note that the reactive blocks are ordered via
> simple static analysis at compile time, and all the compiler looks at
> are the variables that are assigned to and used within the block
> itself, not in any functions called by them. This means that
> yDependent will not be updated when x is updated in the following
> example:

```html
<script>
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    
    const setY = (value) => {
        y = value;
    }
    
    $: yDependent = y;
    $: setY(x);
</script>
```

> Moving the line `$: yDependent = y` below `$: setY(x)` will cause
> `yDependent` to be updated when `x` is updated.

But when I try running the following:

```html
<script>
  let x = 20;
  let y = 0;

  const setY = (value) => {
    y = value;
  };

  $: yDependent = y;
  $: setY(x);
    
  const handleClick = () => {
    y += 1;
  };
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {yDependent} {yDependent === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'} and {y}
</button>
```

I see the button being initialized to 20, so it appears that yDependent IS getting updated when y is updated to the value of x.

It even gets set to 20 if I make handleClick update an entirely unrelated variable z:

```html
<script>
  let x = 20;
  let y = 0;
    let z = 0;

  const setY = (value) => {
    y = value;
  };

  $: yDependent = y;
  $: setY(x);

  const handleClick = () => {
    z += 1;
  };
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {yDependent} {yDependent === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'} and {y}
</button>
```

But NOT if I change "z += 1" to "x += 1".

What's going on?